# Losing my city on a one-city-challenge on complete kills, do I still stand a chance?

Tags: civilization-5

I am currently in a long term Civilization game with a few of my friends. During our previous session I was one single turn away from a science victory, however, the warmonger among us managed to destroy my only city (due to one-city-challenge being on) with his superior fleet. Luckily for me, complete kills is also on, and I still have a decent army. Is it possible for me to capture a landlocked city-state, construct the final piece of the spaceship, and win the game?

Comment: Even if you manage to capture the city-state, it's going to be a LOT worse than your original capital city, so that final spaceship piece is going to take a while to build, and you'll still have to defend your other pieces. and if you already added those pieces, I think you even need to start building from scratch again.

Comment: I agree with your comments @Nzall, and worry for how i might deal with this. The other players seem to be completely convinced that i am out of the competition, so i will likely rely on underplaying my presence and flying under the radar, but it is still quite a challenge. I suppose we will see when we gather for our next session. I will post here again with a few answers when that happens.

Comment: And finally we managed to finish the game. As it turns out @Nzall my plan did NOT work. I got around the problem of poorly developed city-states as i already had adopted all tradition policies in addition to "Spaceflight Pioneers" thus allowing me to purchase a great engineer with saved up faith and use him to finish the spaceship part. However, this did not work because, even though i had no city, entering another city does not capture it, it simply removes it just like it otherwise would on one-city-challenge. The game-mode seams to refer to one city overall, rather than one city at a time.

Answer (score 4):

It seams the answer is NO. One-city-challenge likely refers to one city overall and not one city at a time. In "Brave New World", capturing a city on one-city-challenge seams to remove it regardless to weather your original capital still exists or not.